# Does the series $f(n) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty e^{in} \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$ converge, and if so, does it converge slowly?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, numerical-methods

The series $$f(n) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}},$$

doesn't converge as it is a p-series with $p = 1/2 <1$. If I add an oscillating term to the series such that

$$f(n) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty e^{in} \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}},$$

what can I say about this series? Does it now converge? If so, is it slow to converge? That is, would I need to take a large number of terms to get an accurate numerical approximation?

Comment: you mean $\sum_{n=1}^\infty$

Comment: The series converges by [Dirichlet's test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet's_test).

Comment: @achillehui it is the same thing as the summation by parts

Answer (score 2):

Use the [summation by parts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summation_by_parts) :$$\sum_{n=1}^N z^n n^{-s} = N^{-s} \sum_{n=1}^N z^n + \sum_{n=1}^{N-1} (n^{-s}-(n+1)^{-s}) \sum_{k=1}^n z^k$$ $$ = N^{-s} \frac{z^{N+1}-1}{z-1}+ \sum_{n=1}^{N-1} (n^{-s}-(n+1)^{-s}) \frac{z^{n+1}-1}{z-1}$$ and the conclusion is that $n^{-s}-(n+1)^{-s} = \int_n^{n+1} s x^{-s-1}dx  = sn^{-s-1}+ \mathcal{O}(n^{-s-2})$

The function $Li_s(z) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty z^n n^{-s}$ is the [polylogarithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polylogarithm), and your series is $Li_{1/2}(e^i)$.

Answer (score 2):

A somewhat lower-powered calculation uses that
$$
\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}-\frac1{\sqrt{n+1}}
=\frac1{\sqrt{n}\sqrt{n+1}(\sqrt{n}+\sqrt{n+1})}
\sim\frac1{2n^{3/2}}
$$
so that the series on the right of
$$
(1-z)\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{z^n}{\sqrt{n}}=z-\sum_{n=2}^\infty\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{n-1}}-\frac1{\sqrt{n}}\right)z^n
$$
converges absolutely for all $z:|z|\le 1$.

Comment: But that is not the series I asked about. I don't see how they relate..you have several more terms, a different starting index and no exponential function how does this relate to the series in my question?

Comment: The same semi-telescoping trick works on the partial sums. As $z=e^i\ne 1$, the additional factor $(1-z)$ does not change the convergence behavior.

Answer (score 1):

*This is not an answer but it is too long for a comment.*

Starting from @user1952009's answer $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{e^{i n}}{\sqrt{n}}=\text{Li}_{\frac{1}{2}}\left(e^i\right)$$ we can expand the result in terms of the zeta function and get $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{e^{i n}}{\sqrt{n}}=\frac{\zeta
   \left(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2 \pi }\right)+\zeta \left(\frac{1}{2},1-\frac{1}{2 \pi }\right) } 2+i\frac{\zeta \left(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2 \pi }\right)-\zeta
   \left(\frac{1}{2},1-\frac{1}{2 \pi }\right)} 2$$